# How can we fix an incorrect form of data?

Tags: list-manipulation, data, dataset

```
incorrdata=Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/lk7wiutjf4bx5yk/DataX.dat?dl=1"];
```

How can I fix this data, it should be in the form {$a,\bf{b}$} where **b** is a $3\times3$ matrix and $a$ just a number. Looking at the data directly from the ".dat" file it looks cleaner and only a comma "," is missing (at red points in the pic below) between the main cells as you can see in these first few cells in the .dat file

[image]

However, once I `Import` it to MMA it becomes messy, see a few cells below

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can replace in Notepad "}\n{" to "}, {".

Comment: @yarchik, do you mean manually? may you please elaborate on how can I do that using MMA?

Comment: As far as I know Notepad has Find and Replace function. It is better than to do it manually. I would not use MA for that because this is not a problem of MA, rather the deficiency of the method by which the file was generated. It should be fixed there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
incorrdata = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/lk7wiutjf4bx5yk/DataX.dat?dl=1","Table"];

cleaned = Partition[incorrdata, 3];
cleaned = StringJoin[#] & /@ cleaned;
cleaned = ToExpression[#] & /@ cleaned;
```

Now

```
Dimensions[cleaned]
(* {101, 2} *)
```

And

```
cleaned[[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
cleaned[[2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

etc...